# Scala implicit Long to Serializable

Tags: java, scala

I want to use Scala's Long in Spring's

```
 AbstractPersistable<PK extends Serializable>
```

by using an implicit.

Following example/test does not compile:

```
class A[+T]

object Helper {
  implicit def sLong(l: scala.Long): java.io.Serializable = scala.Long.box(l)
  val a: A[java.io.Serializable] = new A[Long]
}
```

and returns

```
Error:(18, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : com.kiga.db.A[Long]
 required: com.kiga.db.A[java.io.Serializable]
  val a: A[java.io.Serializable] = new A[Long]
```

**Update 1:**

It turns out that

```
implicit def sl(l: A[Long]): A[java.io.Serializable] = new A[java.io.Serializable]
```

does the trick, but the Scala translation from AbstractPersistable's code is wrong. It should be:

```
abstract class AbstractPersistable[PK <: java.io.Serializable]
```

and I want to achieve following:

```
class ScalaPersistable extends AbstractPersistable[scala.Long]
```

Comment: `implicit def sLong(l: A[scala.Long]): A[java.io.Serializable] = new A[java.io.Serializable]`

This should do the trick

Comment: Alright, and what if like it is the case in AbstractPersistable we are dealing with an abstract class? So using

    abstract class A[+T]
    class B extends A[Long]

Comment: The question in your comment is unclear to me. May be editing the main question and adding code example of what you want will make it easier to answer your question, What is your source and what is your target of implicit conversion.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my original post according to your question

Answer (score 2):

An implicit won't make `scala.Long` extend `Serializable`. You can either use `java.lang.Long` or create a class like

```
case class SerializableLong(x: Long) extends Serializable
object SerializableLong {
  implicit def longToSLong(x: Long) = SerializableLong(x)
  implicit def sLongToLong(x: SerializableLong) = x.x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implicit converts from Long to java.io.Serializable, and you need an implicit that converts from A[Long] to A[java.io.Serializable]

Answer (score 0):

So combining both answers.
As Alexey said, you cannot add interface implementation to a class by implicit conversion, you should use some wrapper to have both serialization and `Long` value accessible.

As Javier said, conversion between underlying types does not imply conversion between your container type. For such conversion your type should provide something like [Functor interface](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Functor.html)

E.g. you could define your type such way

```
class A[+T] {
  def map[U](implicit f: T => U): A[U] = ???
}
```

Now having

```
val a = new A[Long]
```

You could use this method like

```
val jA: A[java.lang.Long] = a.map
val sA: A[SerializableLong] = a.map
```

Where `SerializableLong` is taken with conversions from [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687032/210905)